# Fender size: is too wide a problem?

Tags: fenders

AFAIK the width of fender shall be 10-12mm wider than the tyre. But would it cause a problem if the fender is even wider? Like having a 32mm tyre with 52mm fender?

Comment: If AFAYK the width of fender shall be 10-12mm wider than the tyre, how could it not cause a problem if the fender was wider?

Where does AFAYK the width of fender shall be 10-12mm wider than the tyre com from and why would you doubt it?

Answer (score 11):

That's not a problem if you are able to fit your fender onto your frame. The only downside that I can see is that it will slightly increase your air resistance. However, never forget that the biggest source of drag is always on the saddle, so the effect of a wider than necessary fender is rather negligible.

Comment: Note that it's possible for a mudguard to fit apparently sensibly in the frame, but to rub as it flexes, and take the paint off. Even the stock ones did that on my tourer

Comment: I would add: the wider the fender the better the splash protection. True, most water is thrown of centrally from the tyre, but especially with knobbly tyres you get quite some waters from the "shoulder knobs".